# How can I run Drools Rule engine(KIE) on OWL ontology?

Tags: drools, jena, owl, ontology, kie

I have a simple owl ontology which was created by Protege. I want to write and run some rules using Drools for this ontology and checking some actions. I could not find anything about using data in owl format in Drools. Is there any way to do so?

Before I was using Jena for reasoning, can I use Jena for loading my data model and drools for reasoning at the same time?

Comment: How is it possible that nobody knows the answer :D.